# Efficient way to map nested JSON Objects on DTO Objects

Tags: json, spring, dto

I'm working on a Client Rest and I was asking myself if there is an elegant way to map on DTO objects several JSON objects.

I have something like this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "error": [],
    "payload": {
        "list" :
            [{"Id":"012345", name":"IRON MAN", "age":"45"}...]
    }
}
```

So I created several DTO class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseDTO {
    private String status;
    private List<String> error;
    private ResponsePayloadDTO payload;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponsePayloadDTO {
    List<MyObject> list;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyObject {
    private String Id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to manage it?
Thank you

Comment: If you have many rest API and DTO to write, you'd better to use code generator. Tools like https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator might be a good iead, but the question is that you must have the rest API documents in required format.

Answer (score 0):

Add Gson library in pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>

Gson gson = new Gson();
User user= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Respons Dto.class);
```